# How to resize actions column in free jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Sometimes width of column containing inline edit buttons is too small.
Its width cannot changed by mouse.

For example, open demo from

http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/RemovePageHorizontalScrollbar2.htm

and try to resize actions or number column by dragging its right border in header. Column width does not change.

How to fix this so that actions and number column widths can also changed by user ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The referenced example contains the column defined as

```js
{ name: "act", template: "actions", width: 66 }
```

The `width` of the `act` column is fixed and it is `66px`. The template `actions` will be defined as the following (see [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.9.2/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L106-L122) of code):

```js
actions: function () {
    return {
        formatter: "actions",
        width: (this.p != null && this.p.fontAwesomeIcons ? 33 : 37) + (jgrid.cellWidth() ? 5 : 0),
        align: "center",
        label: "",
        autoResizable: false,
        frozen: true,
        fixed: true,
        hidedlg: true,
        resizable: false,
        sortable: false,
        search: false,
        editable: false,
        viewable: false
    };
}
```

You can see that it contains `fixed: true, resizable: false` properties. If you want to change the properties that you can just redefine the values of the template in the column definition:

```js
{ name: "act", template: "actions", width: 66, fixed: false, resizable: true }
```